# Will big box home supply stores cut Zinc-Plated Slotted Angle pieces to size for customers?

Tags: steel, metal-cutting, cutting

Will big box home supply stores cut Zinc-Plated Slotted Angle pieces to size for customers?

Things like

[image]

The shortest they sell at my local home depot is 5 feet, but from one piece, should they be able to cut it into a few pieces for me just like they would for lumber?

If they can't, how could I? Would a reciprocating saw with a blade for metal do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They may.

But if not, you can do it with a reciprocating saw using a metal blade (but watch out; some are only rated for copper or brass) or a manual hack saw. The steel in these angles is pretty mild (soft) and is cut with just a little effort.

The most important thing is to firmly brace the metal before trying to cut.  If you have a vise, that is ideal. If not, you can place the metal over a piece of 2x4 so that both legs are sitting against wood. Clamp the steel to the wood. Firmly attach the 2x4 to some rigid item, screwing or nailing it on temporarily if necessary.

Cut slowly. If the metal binds, you can use a little light oil to lubricate the cut. Each cut will only take a minute or two.

Comment: how about a pair of tin snips? probably provides for far more control than any sort of sawing action.

Comment: @alt Probably too hard/thick for snips unless you were using a power driven pair (not generally DIY equipment). The *Jaws of Life* would do it though.

Comment: upvote for the jaws of life :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use a metal cutting wheel or a hacksaw, but I would be careful about cutting zinc-plated steel, if you inhale too much zinc you could get metal fume fever, you might want to wear a painting respirator, especially if you ever do a lot of cutting of zinc-plated metal. The other poster gave some good tips but I just wanted to be sure that you were aware of the risks of cutting objects containing zinc. Also Home Depot has been known to cut wood for people but Menards doesn't, they usually just sell more sizes instead of having a saw on site like home depot. But I only know that they cut wood, I never asked if they could cut metal, so they might or they might not. Also the fact that it's zinc coated steel might mean they can't because of some safety law, but I'm not sure about that either.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't answer the question, I answered it to the best of my ability. I said they might, the main thing when it comes to a question like this is ask the store, they are the people you should ask considering it's regarding their products and services. Anyways, my feeling is the answer is probably no, because I've never seen them cutting metal.